# app crash on a call to pDialog

Tags: android

when i click my register button app crashes and logcat points to this

```
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password) {

    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    //crash occurs here
    pDialog.setMessage("please wait");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

is there another way i can display the progress dialog?

this is what logcat displays

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.setMessage(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                              at com.chat.RegisterFragment.registerUser(RegisterFragment.java:132)
                                                              at com.chat.RegisterFragment.access$300(RegisterFragment.java:49)
                                                              at com.chat.RegisterFragment$2.onClick(RegisterFragment.java:106)
                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
                                                              at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10891)
                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22533)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Well, what's the logcat say is the issue? Is the dialog null? Where did you assign it?

Comment: you have to share the logcat to us

Comment: Along with the logs, [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: i just added the logcat error

Comment: I am assuming you did'nt initialize the dialog. You need to do pDialog = new ProgressDialog();

Comment: i have done something like this "pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);" and it shows error at "this" so i removed it

Comment: something like "progressDialog (android.content.context) in progressDialog cannot be applied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog is null so you need to initialize it before using it:

```
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                      final String password) {

    String tag_string_req = "req_register";
    pDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("please wait");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
      AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```